# Using mongoose full text search with KeystoneJS paginate

Tags: mongoose, pagination, keystonejs

I have full text search returning results from a Keystone model. The problem is that I am generating these results using `model.find()`. I want to paginate these results, but I can't find a way to use `$text` with `.paginate()`. Is there a way to integrate mongoose full text search with Keystone pagination, or even paginate results from `model.find()`?

**EDIT**

I have tired using `keystone.list('List').paginate().find()` but I receive an error: "callback is not a function." Perhaps there is something else wrong with my code:

```
keystone.list('Document').paginate({
  page: req.query.page || 1,
  perPage: 10,
  maxPages: 6,
})
.find(
  { $text : { $search : req.query.search } },
  { score : { $meta: "textScore" } }
)
.sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
.exec(function(err, results) {
  locals.documents = results;
  next();
});
```

Comment: Have you tried model.paginate().find()?

Comment: I have tried model.paginate().find(), which gives an error because paginate() isn't a function of `model`. I have also tried paginate().model.find(), which does the same thing as if I simply called model.find().

Comment: Try this: keystone.list('MyList').paginate().find() - where 'MyList' is the name of your List.

Comment: I have. I edited the original post with the error received when doing this + my code.

Comment: And where do you use **callback**?

Comment: I don't. That error is coming from mongoose itself (node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1230:16), which makes me think that the problem is that you can't call .find() without `model` or on top of .paginate().

Comment: Ok. There is not a lot of documentation on paginate. Perhaps just build your own pagination using **find()**, **skip()** and **limit()** then.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I managed to do a filter. [Keystone boilerplate](https://github.com/p8ul/keystonejs-react-boilerplate). Below is my todo model

```
import keystone from 'keystone';

const { Field: { Types } } = keystone;

const Todo = new keystone.List('Todo');

Todo.add({
   title: {
   type: String, required: true, default: Date.now,
 },
 description: { type: Types.Html, wysiwyg: true },
 createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

Todo.relationship({ path: 'users', ref: 'User', refPath: 'todos' });
Todo.schema.index({ title: 'text' });
Todo.register();

export default Todo;
```

and the paginated filter

```
export const list = (req, res) => {
const search = new RegExp(req.query.search || '', 'i');
const query = {
  title: search,
};
Todo.paginate({
   page: req.query.page || 1,
   perPage: 5,
   maxPages: 10,
   filters: {
     $or: [query],
   },
 }).sort('-createdAt').exec((err, items) => {
 if (err) return res.status(500).json(err);

   return res.json({
     data: items,
   });
 });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filters like this:

```
keystone.list('Document').paginate({
    page: req.query.page || 1,
    perPage: 10,
    maxPages: 6,
    filters: {
        $text: {
            $search: req.query.search || ''
        },
    },
    optionalExpression: {
        score: {$meta: "textScore"}
    },
})
.sort({ score : { $meta : 'textScore' } })
.exec(function(err, results) {
    locals.documents = results;
    next();
});
```

`paginate` function will pass it into `find` function. [See here](https://github.com/keystonejs/keystone/blob/e6d2c2b9f5a9bc87bde971c7f7a5d1687fd21a85/lib/list/paginate.js#L22).